# Measure service unavailability during upgrade

Tags: microservices, rancher, upgrade, high-availability

I am deploying a microservices - based application using an orchestrator (Rancher specifically).

During the service upgrade (when new images are being pulled and services re-discover one another), there is a small service outage.

What is the best / recommended way to measure the downtime?

I am performing e.g. a

```
watch -n1 'wget --spider http://some.endpoint.whoa'
```

but I want to time the duration of e.g. `502` responses.

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest might be the simplest way to collect the data, but you will have to do quite a bit of work to extract the availability over certain periods.

I think it's fair to say that if you want availability, **you need a monitoring system**. This means having an extra service in your catalogue to continuously probe the availability of your microservices over time. Storing them in a time-series database would allow you to make queries to establish [availability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability) over various periods.

There are many tools which could do this for you. A good starting place would be the [CNCF monitoring landscape](https://landscape.cncf.io/category=monitoring&format=card-mode&grouping=category)

Comment: Whoa there are a lot of services! Any of the top 5 consumer website monitoring services should be able to monitor at this granularity below $5 per month. Pingdom, Statuscake, Uptimerobot etc.